# If $M$ is a compact manifold and $X$ is a vector field in $M$ then $X$ generates a flow.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

**If $M$ is a compact manifold and $X$ is a vector field in $M$ then $X$ generates a flow.**

I know that every flow generates a vector field regardless of whether the manifold is compact or not. But I don't know how to try what I want, any suggestions? Thank you.

*Edit:* I know that if $M$ is a manifold and if $H$ is a local flow on $M$, then there is an induced vector field, which is defined as $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}H(t,p)$. What I want to do is prove something contrary to that, I want to prove that if $M$ is a compact manifold and if $X$ is a vector field in $M$, then there is a flow $H$ in $M$ such that $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}H(t,p)$, that is what I want.

Comment: Equip $M$ with some Riemannian structure. Then flow the point $p$ along the geodesic through it with $\gamma'(0) = X(p)$. (You can do this because $M$ is compact and so any Riemannian structure on it is complete. This idea doesn't work without that additional hypothesis, because, for example, you could take $\mathbb{R}^2$ without the origin and the vector field pointing in toward the origin everywhere; your flow "falls out of the manifold.")

Comment: (Leaving this as a comment instead of an answer because I'm not sure what tools you're allowed to use.)

Comment: Please let us know what do you want clearly. This statement sounds true. Do you want to prove it, to know how to get this flow, or what?

Comment: Are you trying to show that the vector field is *complete*? That is, that, starting at every point, the flow is defined on all of $\Bbb R$? We shouldn't all be having to guess what you are asking.

Comment: @hunter
I am not sure if I can use what you say, I am only seeing a basic course in theory of groups and algebras of Lie and I would like to make a test of this as simple as possible and easy to follow and understand, so that we don't have to use very important results, is that possible?

Comment: @Semsem I know that if $M$ is a manifold and if $H$ is a local flow on $M$, then there is an induced vector field, which is defined as $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}H(t,p)$. What I want to do is prove something contrary to that, I want to prove that if $M$ is a compact manifold and if $X$ is a vector field in $M$, then there is a flow $H$ in $M$ such that $X(p)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}H(t,p)$, that is what I want.

Comment: @ArcticChar 
Why do you think what I am asking is similar to what they ask in that post? How does my question relate to that?

Comment: Fine come back.

Comment: A vector field is complete if it has a global flow. So that question is showing you that on a compact manifold every vector fields has a flow.